# Regex check for name Initials

Tags: regex

I am trying to create a **regex that checks** if one or more **middle-name initials** have the following stucture:

INITIAL.[BLANK]INITIAL.[BLANK]INITIAL.

There can be **multiple Initials** as long as they are followed by a dot (.) - blank spaces are only allowed between two initials (e.g. L. B.)

It should not be possible to have a space after an initial if there's no other initial following.

At the moment, I have the following Regex which doesn't work perfectly as of now:

```
([A-Z]\. (?=[A-Z]|$))+
```

Using regex101, this is an example:
[image: regex output]

As you can see, it still matches the string even though there's a blank space at the end, without having another Initial following.

I am not sure why this is happening. I am just learning regex and would be glad if anyone could provide me with a solution to my problem :)

Comment: Do you mean like this? `\b(?:[A-Z]\. )*[A-Z]\.(?!\S)` https://regex101.com/r/cVroyL/1

Comment: Yes but it shouldn’t be possible to have line breaks

Comment: The pattern does not match line breaks. It asserts what is on the right is not a non whitespace char.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're seeing is because at the last step, your expression reads in `[A-Z]\.` looks ahead for `$` (and finds it). I would express the pattern this way: `(?:[A-Z]\. )*[A-Z]\.$`. Treat the last initial specially because it does not have a final space.

Answer (score 1):

The pattern you tried `([A-Z]\. (?=[A-Z]|$))+` uses a repeated capturing group which will give you the value of the last iteration.

In that repetition you match a space `<code>[A-Z]\. </code>` effectively meaning that it should be present in the match.

---

You could repeat 0+ times matching a char [A-Z] followed by a space to match multiple occurrences.

Then match a char [A-Z] asserting what is on the right is not a non whitespace char.

```
\b(?:[A-Z]\. )*[A-Z]\.(?!\S)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cVroyL/1)

If there can be multiple spaces but it should not match a newline:

```
\b(?:[A-Z]\.[^\S\r\n]*)*[A-Z]\.(?!\S)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fXAjbV/1)